# Exclude filenames with certain prefix in for loop (globbing)

Tags: linux, bash

This is probably quite easy, but I can't figure it out. In a for loop I want to exclude certain files with the prefix `zz` (e.g. `zz131232.JPG`) but I don't know how to exclude these files.

```
for i in *.JPG; do
    # do something
done
```

How do I modify the 'for rule' to exclude files with the prefix `zz`?

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
for i in *.JPG; do
  [[ $i != "zz"* ]] && echo "$i"
done
```

or skip them:

```
for i in *.JPG; do
  [[ $i == "zz"* ]] && continue
  # process the other files here
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with many files you can also use [`GLOBIGNORE`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#globignore) or [`extended globbing`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) to avoid expanding the files you wish to skip in the first place (which might be faster):

```
GLOBIGNORE='zz*'
for file in *.JPG; do
    do_something_with "${file}"
done
# save and restore GLOBIGNORE if necessary
```

or

```
shopt -s extglob # enable extended globbing
for file in !(zz*).JPG; do
    do_something_with "${file}"
done
shopt -u extglob # disable extended globbing, if necessary
```

Note that if there are no `.JPG` files in the current directory the loop will still be entered and `$i` be set to the literal `*.JPG` (in your example), so you either need to check if the file exists inside the loop or use the [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) option.

```
for file in *.JPG; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    do_something_with "${file}"
done
```

or

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file *.JPG; do
    do_something_with "${file}"
done
shopt -u nullglob # if necessary
```

Try the following in your shell to understand what happens without `nullglob`:

```
$ for f in *.doesnotexist; do echo "$f"; done
*.doesnotexist
```